# How to load external file using ClassPathResource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

We have one file on one drive (C:\megzs\realm.properties). We would like to load this file and read the content using the ClassPathResource available in Spring. But we see the file is not found exception. The code we are trying is

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("file:c:/megzs/realm.properties");
Properties prop = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

Here we are using ClassPathResource to load external file. Can ClassPathResource load the external file ? 
And How can we load mutiple properties files (one from classpath and another from absolute path) ??

Answer (score 7):

if you want to access file based resource use FileSystemResource and provide it to PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties() method. Below code reads property file from file system if not exists, it will load it from the classpath. hope it helps.

```
    public static Properties getProperties(String propertyFile) {
    try {
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(propertyFile);
        if (!resource.exists()) {
            resource = new ClassPathResource(propertyFile);
        }
        return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

im loading many properties using `@PropertySource()`
and `properties` will be read using `Environment` object
may be you should try with this approach you approach is not
wrong bt it is somewhat confusing to me

```
@Configuration
    @PropertySource({
        "classpath:config.properties",
        "file:/path/to/application.properties" //if same key, this will 'win'
    })
    public class AppConfig {

        @Autowired
        Environment env;

                public void ReadProperties() {

        String property1 = env.getProperty("property");
        String property2 = env.getProperty("property2");
                }

                //if theres same key found in the second property 
                //file key in the second property file wiil be read
    }
```

Comment: How to load multiple properties files ?? One is on classpath and another one is on absolute path.

Comment: `Resource banner = resourceLoader.getResource("file:c:/file.txt");`
 
`Resource resource = 
          resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:com/testing.txt");`
assign the output to `Resource `

Comment: I am using PropertiesLoaderUtils to load the properties. Using loadProperties() method. This method accepts only single resource object. How can I load multiple properties files ??

Comment: I will give a try for this. I am not sure how to create an object for AppConfig to access env property or the methods.

Comment: We are using spring 3

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.core.env.Environment] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} .. Seeing this exception..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109365/discussion-between-rama-krishna-g-and-priyamal).